# How do you delete a DirParty record in Ax2012?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

I have noticed that when you delete a Worker, the Person record still exists in DirPerson, DirPersonName, DirPartyTable (and a bunch of other related tables).

I assume this is because of the complexities of the whole DirParty engin in Ax2012; probably to ensure that related tables which might contain data is not left without parent records.
But why then is there a function in DirParty class that checks if a party can be deleted(DirParty:: canDeleteParty).  I’ve also tried using the DirParty::autoDeleteParty method without success.  Nothing gets deleted from the DirPartyTable.

Example:

```
static void myLittleDirPartyDeleteJob(Args _args)
{
    DirPartyTable       dirPartyTable;
    DirPerson           dirPerson;
    Common              partyRecord;
    DirParty            dirPartyClass;
    DirPersonRecId      personRecId;
    ;

    select firstOnly * from dirPerson where dirPerson.name == "BONANI VIRGINIA NENGWEKHULU";
    personRecId = DirPerson.RecId;

    //This is after the worker has been deleted on the HcmWorkerListPage form on HRM
    dirPartyTable = DirPartyTable::findRec(DirPerson::find(personRecId).RecId);

    if (dirPartyTable)
    {
        partyRecord = dirPartyTable;
        dirPartyClass = new DirParty(partyRecord);

        if (DirParty::canDeleteParty(dirPartyClass.getPartyRecId(),true))
        {
            DirParty::autoDeleteParty(dirPartyTable.RecId);
        }            
    }
}
```

The above code does not delete anything, nor are there any errors that hits the debugger.

I’ve tried putting it in transaction blocks (ttsbegin, ttscommit); selecting the record forupdate; I’ve even tried forcing a delete with DirPartyTable.doDelete()

When trying any of the above I get the following error:” The value that you are trying to add or subtract creates an invalid utcdatetime”

So my main question is:  Is it possible to delete DirParty (and associated DirPerson; DirPersonName; etc.) tables, or will the party records forever be kept in the Dir* tables, even after deleting employees from the HRModule?

Comment: Have you made sure that the parameter 'delete parties with no roles' is turned on in organizational administration under address book parameters? Not sure but check this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731966.aspx)

Comment: Have checked the parameter, but DirParty record still does not get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that inside autoDeleteParty method there is a check if the AutoDeleteParty parameter is set before deleting, or you can use the code inside in your job.

Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: If you will tick `AutoDeleteParty` field in `DirParameters` table, you will be able to delete records from all these tables by simply deleting a Worker in workers list on a client. 

And in case you have some messy data left in those tables, you still need to tick that field in order `DirParty::autoDeleteParty(_recId);` method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have DirParameters::find().AutoDeleteParty == true

Maybe try running

```
DirParty::canDeleteParty(this.RecId,_showInfoLog)
```

From a job, passing true for _showInfolog

Since the 'autoDeleteParty' method calls this before calling partyTable.delete() but passes false you are unlikely to see any feedback if it does not work